# Naive Bayes for Categorical Features (Non Binary)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, scikit-learn, naive-bayes

How do i use Naive Bayes Classifier (Using sklearn) for a Dataset 
considering that my feature set is categorical, ie more than 2 categories per feature are present.

1. I've looked everywhere, some people have used GaussianNB even though
   the data is categorical (1,2...8)

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://blog.sicara.com/naive-bayes-classifier-sklearn-python-example-tips-42d100429e44&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1567686518476000&usg=AFQjCNGORHakHbk2ZntzNZ1wsTYG6QUhig

2. Some people recommend converting it to One-Hot encoding and then using BernoulliNB which doesn't make sense to me because then the newly created features would have a high correlation which is against one of the core assumptions of Naive Bayes. (For example color feature has 3 values - Blue, Green, Red and we create 3 features out of it; then if Blue is 1 then its obvious that Red and Green will be 0. Hence the dependency)
3. Some people recommend using MultinomialNB which according to me doesn't make sense because it considers feature values to be frequency counts.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you perhaps make your exact question more clear?

Comment: "Some people recommend converting it to One-Hot encoding and then using BernoulliNB which doesn't make sense to me since to me because Bernoulli's can only recognise binary features."  A One-Hot encoding turns categorical features into binary features.

Comment: If you're referring to isolating the features into binary features by creating dummy variables, it won't work for naive bayes because  then the newly created features would have a high correlation which is against one of the core assumptions of Naive Bayes

Comment: I am again unclear as to what you are asking.  If you want to know "how do I get a good answer?", then [the precise context of your problem is necessary information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem).  Or do you just want to know "how do I put categorical data into a format that NB can accept?"

Comment: "How do i put categorical data into a format NB can accept without violating its core assumption of Feature independence ; because using one hot encoding and considering them as binary features violates this principle"

Comment: @Scott Please could you help me out ASAP?